# Setting srcElement in IE results in null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

For reasons I do not have time to discuss, I am coding for IE 8 (only) and need to use `element.fireEvent('eventname', eventObject)` method. Here's my code:

```
var divObj = document.getElementById('div_id');
var evObj = document.createEventObject();
evObj.x = 0; evObj.y = 0;
evObj.srcElement = divObj;
evObj.type = 'onmousedown';
divObj.fireEvent('onmousedown', evObj);
```

When I put a breakpoint and watch the value for `evObj.srcElement`, it is null. The other properties are populated as written.

I checked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx
And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638(v=vs.85).aspx

It seems that I should be able to set this property. Any ideas about why this is null? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Also, just in case anyone is wondering: **divObj** is not null at my breakpoint.

Comment: You're trying to force "involuntary" mouse click of the user. May I ask, why?

Comment: FWIW the reason why you're seeing this issue only with IE 8 seems to be because IE switched event models with IE 9 -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Microsoft-specific_model

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad That is irrelevant to the question, but if you must know: I am trying to create an automated testing tool to complement a proprietary application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Regardless of their values specified in the event object, the values of the four event properties—cancelBubble, returnValue, srcElement,
> and type—are automatically initialized to the values shown in the
> following table.
>
> cancelBubble -> false
>
> returnValue -> true
>
> srcElement -> element on which the event is fired
>
> type -> name of the event that is fired

Hence, it seems that the documentation on the event object is incorrect.